# Earlier plus Concatenate in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, concatenation

is there a way in Power `BI DAX` to use Earlier function on two columns concatenated?

So far, I have been able to just concatenate but unable to use with Earlier function.

This is what I have now.

```
Rank = EARLIER(CONCATENATE('Table1'[Field1], 'Table1'[Field2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it work if you first did a calculated column with
NewColumn = CONCATENATE('Table1'[Field1], 'Table1'[Field2]))

Rank = Earlier (NewColumn)